# How to determine validity of form field from view file?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using the MVC client side validation. I am generating the form fields within the view like this:

```
         <% using (Html.BeginForm(new { useCIM = false }))
           {%>           
        <%: Html.ValidationMessage("auth")%>
        <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Country)%>
        <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Zip)%>
```

I can access the specific Validation Messages within the view like this:

```
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Country)%>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Zip)%>
```

How can I simply determine the validity of a specific field?

UPDATE***

When I try to...

<% if (ModelState["Country"].Errors > 0)

I get an error that "System.Web.Mvc.ModelState' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'"

Comment: have you tried ModelState["Country"].Errors

Comment: When I try to use like like: 
`code`
<% if (ModelState["Country"].Errors > 0)
               { %>

Comment: May I please ask why you need to know which field is invalid on view (.aspx page)? I you want to change something on client side better use CSS class, ASP.NET MVC changes CSS class of all fields with invalid data.

Comment: Emmanuel, I can just style the text inputs with this class, but there are other elements that need to be changed based on which field/s are invalid.

Comment: On .aspx page use `<% ViewData.ModelState["Country"].Errors.Count > 0 %>`

Comment: So ,  '<% ViewData.ModelState["Property"].Errors %>' works if there are errors, but on my initial load i get the error that the object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Check if `ViewData.ModelState != null` before you check for error, something like `ViewData.ModelState != null && ViewData.ModelState["Country"].Errors.Count > 0 `

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
ModelState["Fieldname"].Errors.Count > 0;
```

In .aspx page use

```
<% if(ViewData.ModelState["Fieldname"].Errors.Count > 0)%>
```

On client side check for field with CSS class

```
"input-validation-error"
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Emmanuel N said, if you simply want to know in the view if the field is valid, you can use this:

> ViewData.ModelState.IsValidField("Fieldname")